# Придаточное следствия?

Tags: синтаксис

Можно сказать, что выделенный фрагмент это придаточное следствия? или это условное придаточное с каким-то следственным оттенком?

*Если испугался, **так хоть на глаза мне больше не покажешься**.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, предложения с придаточными условия, уступки, причины, следствия называют предложениями **со значением обусловленности**. Среди них есть как стандартные модели, так и нестандартные (несвободные, фразеологизованные).

Если испугался, так **хоть** на глаза мне больше не покажешься.

**Сравним:** Если испугался, так  на глаза мне больше не покажешься. Это придаточное условное (со значением потенциального условия).

Частица "хоть, хотя бы" имеет значение уступки, можно заменить вводным словом "по крайней мере", то есть мы обозначаем минимальный характер следствия, на которое рассчитываем. Это - структурный элемент, **уточняющий** отношения между главным и придаточным предложением.

Поэтому можно определить предложение **как СПП с придаточным условным с дополнительными значениями следствия и уступки**.